# Grouping by several variables in SAS

Tags: sql, group-by, sas

I want to sum up sales across agents, orders and the date. The following code runs, however, I just receive a duplicate of the total column instead of the sum. Any advice? 
CODE:

```
(Select DISTINCT DATE, CUSTOMER, ORDERNR,
AREA, AGENT, Total, SUM(Total) AS TOTALSUM From data01 WHERE REPORT_DT between '2018-02-24' and '2018-02-25' GROUP BY DATE, CUSTOMER, ORDERNR,
AREA, AGENT, Total, ORDER BY AGENT)
```

Comment: That isn't SAS SQL, which type of SQL are you using, Oracle? The limitations will be based on the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion for clean  your code that contain some error
You don't need  distinct whe  use GROUP BY and you have a wrong comma after the word Total in group by

```
  (Select  
      DATE
      , CUSTOMER
      , ORDERNR
      , AREA
      , AGENT
      , Total
      , SUM(Total) AS TOTALSUM 
    From data01 
    WHERE REPORT_DT between '2018-02-24' and '2018-02-25'
    GROUP BY DATE
        , CUSTOMER
        , ORDERNR
        , AREA
        , AGENT
        , Total
  ORDER BY AGENT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Total` from the `GROUP BY`:

```
Select DATE, CUSTOMER, ORDERNR, AREA, AGENT, SUM(Total) AS TOTALSUM
From data01 
where REPORT_DT between '2018-02-24' and '2018-02-25' 
group by DATE, CUSTOMER, ORDERNR, AREA, AGENT;
```

Comment: Thank you! It really turned out that I cannot include the variable total or the aggregate of it in the group by statement.